# java swing stop function

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem trying to stop a process during execution.
My process consists of a csv parser. My intention was to create a start button that will run the csv parser, and a stop the button to halt the csv parser. I used a function system.exit(), the whole program closes. What I want to do is just to interrupt the csv function. When I use the thread.sleep(), the stop button hangs there and there's no way to press the start button. Many thanks!

```
private void stopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
st = 0;
if (st = 0)
{ }



}                                        

private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
st =1;
if (st = 1){
Start1 test = new Start1();
test.sbutton();}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Thread.sleep(Time)
But remember to run your csv parser in a separate Thread. If you are having only one thread then your entire application hangs.
For example:

```
class ParserStarter implements Runnable{
    void someMethodWhereYouStartParser(){
       Thread t=new Thread(this);
       t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        CSVParser cp=new CSVParser();
    }
}
class CSVParser{
  //here you can write your start/stop logic using Thread.sleep();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the given information try it this way,

1. Create a new thread.
2. Execute the csv parser or whatever from the new thread.
3. When you want to stop this, destroy the thread.

If this didnt help you, post a rephrased question with an [SSCCE.](http://www.sscce.org)